# JavaScript match key/value list to days

Tags: javascript, json, object

I am creating a class listing from a JSON endpoint from a class management system called Jackrabbit. The endpoint I pull from is https://app.jackrabbitclass.com/jr3.0/Openings/OpeningsJSON?orgID=537284 (this includes my sample class listing). From a previous question I got help for putting this into a dynatable. However, now I am also trying to display the day a class is on, but the JSON endpoint formats the days a class is on like so: `"meeting_days":{"mon":false,"tue":false,"wed":false,"thu":false,"fri":true,"sat":false,"sun":false}`. I am trying to convert this such that if it says `"mon":true` it would show as Monday (or Mon) in the table. If multiple days are true I'd like to list them.

This is the javascript/html I currently have: https://jsfiddle.net/pikles/uqca9df0/28/

```js
function tConvert(time) {
    // Check correct time format and split into components
    time = time.toString().match(/^([01]\d|2[0-3])(:)([0-5]\d)(:[0-5]\d)?$/) || [time];

    if (time.length > 1) { // If time format correct
        time = time.slice(1); // Remove full string match value
        time[5] = +time[0] < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM'; // Set AM/PM
        time[0] = +time[0] % 12 || 12; // Adjust hours
    }
    return time.join(''); // return adjusted time or original string
}

function dictionaryDay(dictDay) {
    var days = ""
    for (var day in dictDay) {
        if (dictDay.hasOwnProperty(day) === true) {
            days = days + day
        } else {}
    }
    return days
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("https://app.jackrabbitclass.com/jr3.0/Openings/OpeningsJSON?orgID=537284", function(data) {
        var data_arr = [];
        $.each(data.rows, function(key, data_value) {
            data_arr.push({
                'class': data_value.name,
                'coach': data_value.instructors[0],
                'day': dictionaryDay(data_value.meeting_days),
                'age': data_value.min_age.substr(2, 2) + ' +',
                'openings': data_value.openings.calculated_openings,
                'time': tConvert(data_value.start_time),
                'tuition': data_value.tuition.fee,
            });
        });
        $("#classes").dynatable({
            dataset: {
                records: data_arr
            },
            features: {
                paginate: false,
                recordCount: false,
                search: false
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Dynatable/0.3.1/jquery.dynatable.min.js"></script>
<table id="classes" class="ui celled table">
    <thead>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>Coach</th>
        <th>Day</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Openings</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Tuition</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The code in question that I have been currently working on to solve is `dictionaryDay` function.

However this lists every single day when it returns the days. I thought this may be a issue where the `=== true` should be `=== "true"`, however when I do this - no days are returned.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Warm Regards,
Piklet

Comment: Thank you adiga - I didn't know you could do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Object.hasOwnProperty` that return true if the object contains the property. It doesn't read the value but only the key to check if it exist in the object.

Here is your function corrected:

```
function dictionaryDay (dictDay) {
  var days = ''
  for (var day in dictDay) {
    // day is the key name ('mon'|'thu'|'wen'...)
    // dictDay['mon'] make reference to the value (true|false)
    if (dictDay[day]) {
      days = days + ' ' + day
    }
  }
 return days
}
```